# Find all related documents of two related fields in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am new to Elasticsearch and I need some help to retrieve related documents from Elasticsearch

I have an index with the following structure

| parent | child | ... |
| 0000001 | 0000001 | ... |
| 0000001 | 0000002 | ... |
| 0000002 | 0000003 | ... |
| 0000003 | 0000003 | ... |
| 0000004 | 0000005 | ... |
| 0000006 | 0000006 | ... |

I need a query or solution in Elasticsearch to retrieve all the related documents of 0000001 that is

| parent | child | ... |
| 0000001 | 0000001 | ... |
| 0000001 | 0000002 | ... |
| 0000002 | 0000003 | ... |
| 0000003 | 0000003 | ... |

0000001-> 0000002 -> 0000003

Thank you

Comment: I can't understand how the documents are related to each other. 0000003 looks completely unrelated to 0000001. And what is ... ?

Comment: It is related because 0000003 is related to 0000002 and 0000002 is related to 0000001 and "..." means other details in the record I'm sorry if it is confusing..